# How to create a Cloud Storage image URL in Flutter code?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I have an 'image' stored in a folder in Cloud Storage that I want to use as a default image whenever new users sign up using email and password.  Users will have the option to add their own image once their account is created but I want all users to start with a default image.  Flutter, according to different questions/answers on SO, can't read the (gs)URLs that Cloud Storage uses natively to describe the location of an uploaded file.  How do I create a url that Flutter can read?

My Cloud Storage URL is:
gs:// shopping-app.appspot.com/defaultUserImage/default_user_icon.jpg

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use default bucket, you can get an URL like:

```
await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('<file>').getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had to clean up other code but your solution was perfect.  No errors and I have the exact behavior I desired.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The FlutterFire documentation for Cloud Storage on [download URLs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#download-urls) covers precisely what you're asking. From there:

> In many use-cases, you may wish to display images stored on a storage bucket within your application, using Firebase as a scalable and cost-effective Content Distribution Network (CDN). Firebase allows you to retrieve a long-lived download URL which can be used. To request a download URL, call the [`getDownloadURL` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/getDownloadURL.html) on a reference:
>
> ```
> Future<void> downloadURLExample() async {
>   String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
>      .ref('users/123/avatar.jpg')
>       .getDownloadURL();
>
>   // Within your widgets:
>   // Image.network(downloadURL);
> }
> ```

You can get a `StorageReference` for the `gs://` URL you have by passing it to the [`FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL()` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/refFromURL.html).

Comment: I actually did not review that specific documentation.  Thanks for the link and the code help.  I'm going to read through the documentation in the link and change my code in a few places now that I have an idea what to do.